# I want to run artisan commands on my online sever

Tags: php, laravel

Hello guys i have finished developing my  website the next question is can i run then Artisan Commands on the web server like go daddy? just like PHP artisan up

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  You just need to enable SSH access.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hello i came to realise that the server was so cheap to allow ssh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just contact support to enable SSH Access and you will be able to run artisan commands through your terminal.

After your SSH access is enabled, you can use [Putty](https://www.putty.org/) or run the `ssh` command in your linux terminal to connect with the server:

```sh
ssh username@hostname:port
```

Some useful links:

[How To Use SSH To Connect To A Remote Server In Linux Or Windows](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ssh-to-connect-to-remote-server-linux-or-windows)

[Beginner’s Guide To Setting Up SSH On Linux And Testing Your Setup](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/beginners-guide-setting-ssh-linux-testing-setup/)

[Connecting via SSH to your server](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403684/connecting-via-ssh-to-your-server)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

just connect

`ssh username@hostname:port`

then type

`php /path/to/project/ artisan ...`